# Creating Submenu inside a submenu with css

Tags: html, css

I am creating a navigation with a submenu inside a submenu but its not working properly. I already tried samples from the internet but when I am implementing it. I encounter some problems. I can't target the submenu properly. I am new to this and I hope you can help me on this.

```css
#cssmenu {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: left;
  height:40px;
  margin-left:100px;
  margin-top:10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  width: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ece6e8;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #d9ced2;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -o-border-radius: 10px;
  width:450px;
  margin-left:930px;
}
#cssmenu > ul li#responsive-tab {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.right {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub {
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
/*border color*/
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ece6e8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d9ced2;
  border-top: 0 none;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul li {
  display: block;
}

#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub > a {
  background-image: url('images/caret.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 90% -95%;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub > a.active,
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub > a:hover {
  background: #d80041 url('images/caret.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: 90% 195%;
}
#cssmenu > ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px 11px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #747474;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;
  background: #8f1941;
}

#cssmenu > ul li a.active,
#cssmenu > ul li a:hover {
  background: #d80041;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #000;
}
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
        <li class='has-sub'>
            <a href="#xl_xr_page_profile" target="_self" onclick="return(xr_nn());"><span>profile</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#xl_xr_page_departments" onclick="return(xr_nn());"><span>divisions</span></a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='xl_xr_page_admin%20&amp;%20hr'><span>admin & hr</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href='#xl_xr_page_finance'><span>finance</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href='#xl_xr_page_sales%20&amp;%20marketing'><span>sales and marketing</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href='#xl_xr_page_i.t.'><span>i.t.</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href='#xl_xr_page_operations'><span>operations</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href='#xl_xr_page_research%20&amp;%20development'><span>research & development</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href='#xl_xr_page_creative%20&amp;%20technical'><span>creative & technical</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href='#xl_xr_page_project%20management'><span>project management</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href='#xl_xr_page_production'><span>production</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href='#xl_xr_page_logistic%20&amp;%20installation'><span>logistic & installation</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <li><a href="#xl_xr_page_facility" onclick="return(xr_nn());"><span>facility</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#xl_xr_page_partners" onclick="return(xr_nn());"><span>partners</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#xl_xr_page_clients" onclick="return(xr_nn());"><span>clients</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='has-sub'>
            <a href="#xl_xr_page_business%20units" onclick="return(xr_nn());"><span>business units</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#xl_xr_page_signage%20&amp;%20display" onclick="return(xr_nn());"><span>signage & displays</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return(xr_nn());"><span>traffic signs</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return(xr_nn());"><span>large format digital printing</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return(xr_nn());"><span>architectural detailing & fit-outs</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return(xr_nn());"><span>awards & gifts</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return(xr_nn());"><span>luxury & hospitality accessories</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return(xr_nn());"><span>engraving & cutting services</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return(xr_nn());"><span>electroplating services</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='active' style="position: relative"><a href="#xl_xr_page_news" onclick="return(xr_nn());"><span>news</span></a></li>
        <li class='last' style="position: relative"><a href="#xl_xr_page_contact%20us" onclick="return(xr_nn());"><span>contacts</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I really need help. Thanks!

Comment: You haven't actually told us what the problem is.

Comment: Oh im sorry the problem is that the profile has a submenu then inside it has a button division which has another submenu but I cant change the location where it will appear. It must be on the right side of the division button. But I cant target the element properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check with the below link.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/PGDKE/)

```
  #nav {
width:800px;
margin:30px 50px;;
padding: 0;
float:left;
}
#nav li {
 list-style: none;
 float: left; 
 padding:0 10px;
}
//daf adf 
/*--temp--*/
#nav ul ul li {
clear:left;
}
#nav ul ul {
position:absolute;
left:14em;
top:0;
}
#nav ul ul li a {
display:block;
padding: 3px 15px;
color: #242424;
text-decoration: none;
font-size:13px;
font-family:"Lato" !important;
}
/*--end temp--*/
#nav li a {
display: block;
padding: 3px 15px;
color: #242424;
text-decoration: none;
font-size:13px; 
font-family:"Lato" !important;
}
 #nav a:hover {
color:#367FB3;
}
#nav a:active {
color:#367FB3;
}
#nav li ul {
display: none; 
width: 14em; /* Width to help Opera out */
background-color:transparent;
z-index:666;
}
#nav li:hover ul, #nav li.hover ul {
display: block;
position: absolute;
margin:0px -10px;
padding:0px; 
}
#nav li:hover ul ul {
  display:none; 
}
#nav li ul li:hover ul {
  display:block
}
#nav li:hover li, #nav li.hover li {
float: none; 
line-height:30px;
}
#nav li:hover li a, #nav li.hover li a {
 background-color:#367FB3;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:13px; 
 font-family:"Lato" !important;
}
#nav li li a:hover {
background-color:#52baff; 
color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll try to use this. But can you tell me whats wrong with my menu? thank you.